# C++ error: Double and 3d Vector

Tags: c++, double

I got an error when compile the below code saying that "called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer". Because 'position' is a 3d vector, so I was trying to access each element of the vector.

```
    int  k=1;
    int  m=1;

    double x, y, z;

    x=position.x;
    y=position.y;
    z=position.z;

    for (int j = 3; j < 1000 ; j++)
    {
     x(j) = 2 * x(j-1) - x(j-2) + (delta_t * delta_t * (-1.0*k/m) * x(j-1));
    }
```

Comment: `x(j)` - What are you trying to do? I advise you to go through a basic tutorial.

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP doesn't show minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: You need to understand the C++ basics. Read about accessing arrays and vectors.

Comment: You *did* access each element of `position` - the x element is in `x`, the y is in `y`, and the z is in `z`. The rest of the code looks like some kind of pseudo code to implement a summation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually have to keep track of `x(j)`, `x(j-1)`, and `x(j-2)` all as separate variables (using the syntax `x(j)` is akin to calling a function `x()` with argument `j`, which is not what you want).

Try:

```
double xj, xj_m1, xj_m2;
xj_m1 = position.x;
xj_m2 = position.x;
for (int j = 3; j < 1000 ; j++) {
    xj = 2 * xj_m1 - xj_m2 + (delta_t * delta_t * (-1.0*k/m) * xj_m1);

    //Update xj_m2 and xj_m1 for the next iteration
    xj_m2 = xj_m1;
    xj_m1 = xj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do it:

```
x=position.x;
```

You expect that position.x is an array?
To access to an element in a vector, you can use the [] operator:

```
std::vector<int> myIntVector = { 1, 2, 3 };
int i = myIntVector[0]; // i = 1 because myIntVector[0] is the first element of myIntVector
```

The variable position looks like a coordinate vector, so it's not an array, it's just a class / struct like this:

```
struct Vector3
{
    double x, y, z;
};
```

In other words, position.x is just a number.